# Why is NPE thrown when finishing Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, android-fragments, activity-lifecycle

I have an error that has been driving me crazy for days.  Unfortunately, I can not show you the code for two reason, my boss will not appreciate it and the codebase is too large to share.  The error occurs whenever the Activity is finishing.  Weather it be because I call finish() or because the os destroys it.

The question is, what is (or could) cause execPendingActions() in FragmentManagerImpl to throw a NPE at line 1196.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions() line: 1196 
FragmentManagerImpl$1.run() line: 375   
Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 587   
Handler.dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92   
Looper.loop() line: 126 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3997    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 491  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 841  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 599 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: I think that you really need to post some code...

Comment: I cant.  Just think of the question as 'what could cause a NPE to be thrown at line 1196 of FragmentManagerImpl'

Comment: Is it for every activiity or just this one? Can u at least describe what the code is doing... ?

Comment: There are only two activities - Main  and Preferences, 8 Fragments, and 25 or so classes plus a service. Main is about 600 lines and it's the only one that crashes when exiting.

Comment: @Gallal You could try using the compat library and debugging that. Alternatively try and reproduce in a cut down sample app.

Comment: @PJL your suggestion helped me find what I was doing wrong.  If you post it as an answer, I'll reward your the 50 reputation, and I'll post my answer.

Comment: @Gallal Thanks, glad it helped solve your problem.

Comment: @Gallal please can you check mine too? I got approx same problem.please check http://stackoverflow.com/q/13266795/1516775

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the compat library and debugging that.

Alternatively try and reproduce in a cut down sample app.

Comment: This answer helped.  It lead to to find out that in one of the fragment's onDestroy() I was calling a method on a null reference.  Unfortunately, the stacktrace did not make that clear.  Thanks @PJL!

Answer (score 2):

When talking about finishing the activities: Are you trying to `finish()` the activity from a View? Are correctly sending `MyClass.this.finish()`?

It looks to me that OS force it to close due NPE. Something is wrong with the fragments. Something is Null among them. Could you at least paste the line where it crashes?

Comment: The line is 'finish();' from within the Activity.

Comment: Fragments are manipulated in over 20 locations across the app, so it is hard for me to show you what I do with the Fragments that may be causing this.

Comment: Check how you finish the activity, check if you are finishing the activity from fragment, check if you inflated correctly.

Comment: Try starting the activities of the fragments for result, and try finishing them with result... and then finish() the whole activity... Just an idea, that might avoid this.

Comment: I mean removing the rest of the fragments and then finishing.

Comment: Use `getActivity()` to get the activity associated with that fragment.

Answer (score 2):

You may be hitting a bug in fragment manager where it doesn't clear its list of pending transactions before being destroyed.  This can happen if you commit a transaction after your state has been saved, using FragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss(). You may be able to work around it with this code in your activity:

```
@Override void onDestroy() {
    getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried this already but it doesn't work.  It returns false which, according to the documentation, means that there were no pending transactions to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

The NullPointerException is caused by the fact that Activity's Handler is unset from the FragmentManager, so a "solution" that will prevent the crash is the following:

```
public void onDestroy(){ 
        super.onDestroy(); 
        try { 
            Field mActivityField = getFragmentManager().getClass().getDeclaredField("mActivity");
            mActivityField.setAccessible(true);
            mActivityField.set(getFragmentManager(), this);

            Field mPendingActionsField = getFragmentManager().getClass().getDeclaredField("mPendingActions");
            mPendingActionsField.setAccessible(true);
            mPendingActionsField.set(getFragmentManager(), null);


            Field f = Activity.class.getDeclaredField("mHandler");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            Handler handler = (Handler) f.get(this);
            handler.close(); 
        } catch (Throwable e) {

        } 
}
```