# NPE in FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate()

Tags: android

When I quickly press back, back, back on my mobile I got following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1378)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:437)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:452)
at android.app.Activity.onBackPressed(Activity.java:2123)
at com.swipemaster.activities.CommonActivity.onBackPressed(CommonActivity.java:16)
at com.swipemaster.activities.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:1)
at com.swipemaster.activities.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:62)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Tested on Android 4.0.4 and 2 devices: Sony Xperia MT27i and ST23i. On 2.2.1 and Galaxy Mini this problem doesn't occur. Can anybody help me?

`CommonActivity` class:

```
public class CommonActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        MusicPlayer.continueMusic = true;
        super.onBackPressed(); // this is CommonActivity.java:16
    }
```

Comment: Was it observed on many devices or just some particular? (I'm asking, because I've checked 4.0.4_r1.2 and 4.0.4_r1.1 code and there's no code at FragmentManager.java:457)

Comment: I don't have any other devices with 4.0.4. The crash is on Sony Xperia MT27i. `FragmentManager` is an abstract class, the code is in `FragmentManagerImpl`. https://github.com/grantland/android-support-v4/blob/master/src/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java#L377

Comment: Are You adding some fragments and rely on fragments backstack? Are You doing it in onResume() of some activity?

Comment: It was coded using API 7. I didn't use any fragments nor backstack in my code.

Comment: I'm showing a Dialog in GameActivity.onResume() (GameActivity is invoked after choosing a level in PlayLevelsActivity). This Dialog in his onBackPressed() has dismiss() and gameActivity.finish().

Comment: is it reproducible without that dialog?

Comment: Yes. I updated exception (on ST23i it's richer). I'm also calling overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out) from some places to have nice animations... but I don't know if this is relevant...

Comment: Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774505/why-is-npe-thrown-when-finishing-activity the problem might be in some of onDestroy() methods.

Comment: This helped me to fix this problem. I will post my solution for other people. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you quickly press 2 times back button on your device, the `onBackPressed()`  method is also called 2 times. This is causing the problem.

Solution:

Look into all your `onBackPressed()` methods. Do you have something, that can cause problems, because of being called 2 times? For example, this can be a call to `postDelayed()`, which was mine case. If yes, add a flag assuring that your `onBackPressed()` body will be executed only once, despite the number of back button clicks:

```
private boolean backAlreadyPressed = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if (backAlreadyPressed)
    {
        return;
    }
    backAlreadyPressed = true;

    // old implementation of onBackPressed()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding the issue is in this call `return popBackStackState(mActivity.mHandler, null, -1, 0);` in the following function:

```
 @Override
 public boolean popBackStackImmediate() {
     checkStateLoss();
     executePendingTransactions();
     return popBackStackState(mActivity.mHandler, null, -1, 0);
 }
```

From [Android source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r1.2/android/app/FragmentManager.java/).

So, the real question as I see it: Why `mActivity` is null at that function (or some  vendor-specific field)?

As per the comments the issue was observed only on signle device, so I could suggest the following:

- Verify the issue on some other device to detect if it's reproducible (because in stock android 4.0.4 there's no code at `FragmentManager.java:457`);
- Try to build app for API 15 or API 16 and check if issue remain;
- Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774505/why-is-npe-thrown-when-finishing-activity) replies, the problem might be in one of `onDestroy()` methods;
- Investigate applications code to find out if some part of it calls `finish()` for all activities or does some handling to exit from the app (e.g. tries to handle multiple back presses as exit from app);
- Try to workout some hack (e.g. handling of back with small 100ms delay). But for this way I would suggest You to be sure that the issue is vendor-specific and put that hack under check of [Build.MANUFACTURER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MANUFACTURER);